# How to generate a page in report for each data row using SSRS

Tags: ssrs-2008

I am working on developing an SSRS report.I have a table in which student name and 6 subjects marks is stored in each row. My problem statement goes like this ---> lets say if 10 rows of data is present in table then I want to create report card/ marksheet for each student in new page but inside a same report. (I.e. 10 pages in one report). Then convert the report containing 10 pages to PDF format and save it in some folder. 
Can anyone show some possibilities to achieve my problem statement.
Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 0):

Usually you'll want to use a **List** object to separate your report by student. You would group the list by student in your report. Then set a Page Break in the List with the location to **Between** each group so that it separates each student into a separate page.

Then you can put charts, tables and other object inside the list and it will repeat with the list group (in your case, each student).

[MSDN: Lists](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/2014/reporting-services/report-design/create-invoices-and-forms-with-lists-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-2017)

In this report I made below, the List is highlighted in Red and groups by each site. It just has a table inside. When it's run each site gets it's own page with a list of their people.

[image]

Keep in mind that a List is actually just a Tablix with only one data cell - with the column and row headers removed.